# Is it correct to use "derive from" in the following context?

Tags: verb-usage

According to dictionaries, "to derive" means "to get something from something else" and "to come from something". But I'm not sure if it can be used in the following context. By "derived from" l mean they used Sophocles's work as their source. My search for similar sentences was of no avail.

"Among the authors who derived from Sophocles were ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/derive), the verb derive means "to get something from something else". You use it in a sentence like this:

> [subject] derived [verb object] from [preposition object]

Compare that with your sentence:

> Among the authors who derive from Sophocles were ...

Note that there is no verb object in your sentence. You can correct it by adding a verb object like this:

> Among the authors who derive **ideas** from Sophocles were ...

You would be more likely to convert this to a passive voice sentence:

> Among the authors whose ideas are derived from Sophocles were ...